# Python tree storing expressions from json input file

Tags: python, json, tree

I have an input json file, and trying to store the variables and their values in a tree using python, then output the result in a file. The json file contains integers, tuples of expressions, and sets.

Part of my json file:

```
{
    "declaration-list" : [
    {
            "declared-variable" : "x0",
            "value" : 1
          },
    {
            "declared-variable" : "x1",
            "value" : 2
          },
    {
            "declared-variable" : "x2",
            "value" : {
                "operator" : "set",
                "arguments" : [
                    {
                        "variable" : "x0"
                      },
                    {
                        "variable" : "x1"
                      }
                  ]
              }
          },
    {
            "declared-variable" : "x3",
            "value" : {
                "operator" : "set",
                "arguments" : [
                    {
                        "operator" : "tuple",
                        "arguments" : [
                            1,
                            2
                          ]
                      },
                    {
                        "operator" : "tuple",
                        "arguments" : [
                            3,
                            4
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
              }
          },

 ]
}
```

The output for that input should be:

```
let x0 be 1;
let x1 be 2;
let x2 be {1, 2};
let x3 be {(1, 2), (3, 4)};
```

So far all I've got is this, and I have no idea where or how to start storing them all in a tree etc.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('input.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

for x in data["declaration-list"]:
    print "let %s be %s" % ((x["declared-variable"]), (x["value"]))

data_file.close()
```

Which only prints out e.g. "let x0 be 1" correctly, but doesn't even remember them. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a start. It uses recursion to take apart the JSON and build a data structure. The data structure is essentially a somewhat-abstract Python implementation of the JSON structure. You should be able to apply the same recursive approach to generate whatever flavor of output text you need.

```
json_data = {
    "declaration-list" : [
        { "declared-variable": "x0", "value": 1 },
        { "declared-variable": "x1", "value": 2 },
        { "declared-variable": "x2",
          "value" : {
              "operator": "set",
              "arguments": [
                  { "variable": "x0" },
                  { "variable": "x1" }
              ]
          }
        },
        { "declared-variable" : "x3",
          "value" : {
              "operator" : "set",
              "arguments" : [
                  {
                      "operator": "tuple",
                      "arguments": [ 1, 2 ]
                  },
                  {
                      "operator": "tuple",
                      "arguments": [ 3, 4 ]
                  }
              ]
          }
        },
    ]
}

def parse_declaration(declinfo):
    vname = declinfo['declared-variable']
    rvalue = parse_rvalue(declinfo['value'])
    return ('let', vname, rvalue)

def _rv_parse_set(valinfo):
    assert valinfo['operator'] == 'set'
    args = [parse_rvalue(a) for a in valinfo['arguments']]
    return ('set', args)

def _rv_parse_tuple(valinfo):
    assert valinfo['operator'] == 'tuple'
    args = valinfo['arguments']
    return ('tuple', args)

_rv_parser = {
    "set": _rv_parse_set,
    "tuple":_rv_parse_tuple,
}

def parse_rvalue(valinfo):
    try:
        if 'operator' in valinfo:
            op = valinfo['operator']
            return _rv_parser[op](valinfo)
        elif 'variable' in valinfo:
            return ('variable', valinfo['variable'])

    except TypeError:
        return ('value', valinfo)

def parse_json(json_data):
    declaration_list = json_data['declaration-list']

    for i in declaration_list:
        print(parse_declaration(i))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse_json(json_data)
```

Output is:

```
('let', 'x0', ('value', 1))
('let', 'x1', ('value', 2))
('let', 'x2', ('set', [('variable', 'x0'), ('variable', 'x1')]))
('let', 'x3', ('set', [('tuple', [1, 2]), ('tuple', [3, 4])]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this will be a great start

Answer (score 3):

This is a coursework question, I'm reporting this.